# NO symbol at the beginning of a symbol line?

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

Is there a simple way NOT to have a symbol at the beginning of a line?
I need to add symbols on a line each x meters.
Symbology > add symbol > line of symbol works fine, but there is always a symbol added on the very first point of the line.
How can it be removed?
Actual situation:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter a value equal to your marker spacing as [`offset along line`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?highlight=marker%20line#line-symbols:%7E:text=of%20multipart%20geometries.-,Offset%20along%20line,-%3A%20the%20markers).

If you e.g. enter `50 m` as your offset, your first marker will be displayed 50 m "down the line".

[image]

Comment: I guess that is I had already done, but it does not work, see screenshot above

Comment: You haven't added an offset.

Comment: Indeed. Not that clear in French... Thanks